# Using JS, how to implement an e-commerce style faceted search, with an array of possible criteria which are themselves nested values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter, e-commerce

Something I often see in e-commerce websites is a sidebar with checkboxes for various filtering values. Many of these can be checked, and adding new values further narrows down your search.

I want to implement something similar for metadata pertaining to digital media. I have an array of possible filters, each of which is an object `{nameOfProperty: ['Value1', 'Value2']}`. The idea is to return results that satisfy ALL of the criteria in an array of attributes `{value: 'Value1', trait_type: 'NameOfProperty'}`.

See example:

```
const arr = [
  { metadata: { json: { 
    attributes: [
      { value: "Copycat Fridge Artist", trait_type: "Artist" },
      { value: "Fridges Vol. 2", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Fridges Playlist", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Image", trait_type: "Artwork Type" }
    ]
  },

  { metadata: { json: { 
    attributes: [
      { value: "Copycat Fridge Artist", trait_type: "Artist" },
      { value: "Fridges Vol. 1", trait_type: "Collection" },
      { value: "Videos Playlist", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Video", trait_type: "Artwork Type" }
    ]
  },

  { metadata: { json: { 
    attributes: [
      { value: "Cool Original Artist", trait_type: "Artist" },
      { value: "Fridges Vol. 1", trait_type: "Collection" },
      { value: "Videos Playlist", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Video", trait_type: "Artwork Type" }
    ]
  }
];
```

and an array of filters

```
filters: [{Artwork Type: ['Image', 'Video']},
          {Playlist: ['Videos Playlist']},
          {Artist: ['Cool Original Artist']}]
```

In this scenario, I want to see images *or* videos, *only* from the Videos Playlist and then *only* ones by Cool Original Artist. The filter should return arr[2].

The filters can be many and varied, and not every item in the array has the name number of attributes.

If there is a name for this kind of search/filter I am not aware of it, so apologies if this has been asked before. It's something I've encountered many times, but never tried to code myself, and I'm struggling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I filter the `arr` values in a reducer.

```js
const arr = [
  { metadata: { json: { 
    attributes: [
      { value: "Copycat Fridge Artist", trait_type: "Artist" },
      { value: "Fridges Vol. 2", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Fridges Playlist", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Image", trait_type: "Artwork Type" }
    ]
  }}},

  { metadata: { json: { 
    attributes: [
      { value: "Copycat Fridge Artist", trait_type: "Artist" },
      { value: "Fridges Vol. 1", trait_type: "Collection" },
      { value: "Videos Playlist", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Video", trait_type: "Artwork Type" }
    ]
  }}},

  { metadata: { json: { 
    attributes: [
      { value: "Cool Original Artist", trait_type: "Artist" },
      { value: "Fridges Vol. 1", trait_type: "Collection" },
      { value: "Videos Playlist", trait_type: "Playlist" },
      { value: "Video", trait_type: "Artwork Type" }
    ]
  }}}
];

const filters = [
  { "Artwork Type": ["Image", "Video"] },
  { Playlist: ["Videos Playlist"] },
  { Artist: ["Cool Original Artist"] }
];

// reduce the arr by matching with each filter object
const result = filters.reduce((remaining, curr) => {

  // assign filter attribute name and values
  const [name, values] = Object.entries(curr)[0];
  
  // do filtering
  return remaining.filter(({metadata: { json: {attributes}}}) =>
    attributes.find((a) => a.trait_type === name && values.includes(a.value))
  );
}, arr);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the approach. 

Arr, in my scenario, is deeply-nested metadata.

Is it possible to destructure the nested array into the filter() call, e.g  `return remaining.filter(({ metadata: { json: { attributes }}}) => attributes.find((a) => a.trait_type === name && values.includes(a.value))), mainArrayOfNestedObjects)`?

Comment: @JamieHarding If the structure is `const arr = { metadata: { json: [  {  attributes: [ ...`, you only need to pass `arr.metadata.json` to `filters.reduce` as second parameter instead of just `arr`.

Comment: The structure is `constr arr = [ { metadata: { json: { attributes: [ { ...`

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm still having issues, I think because the attributes array doesn't always contain the same trait_types as the filter conditions.

Comment: @JamieHarding You are welcome! Usually the question author marks helpful answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), which will add reputation to himself and the answerer. It also helps the others to understand that the question has been answered.